# Drop Down Category Menu Not Working

Tags: jquery, css, dropdown

If you look on my [website](http://www.microcapstars.com), at the top menu under Member's Only, the dropdown menu is not showing the three pages that are listed as sub-pages under the menu category. I know that the back end is fine, and this theme is an older one that I was using on another site and know this functionality works. Just thinking that maybe something is off with the JS?

This is the code in the header menu:

```
<div id="main-nav">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu'       => 'Main Navigation',
        'container'  => false,
        'items_wrap' => '<ul class="nav">%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'      => 3,
        'walker'     => new
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make a custom link with the name "Members only" and link to "#". Then add the sub-menu page.